# How to add a total row for only one column in a data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame named bill like this:

```
print(bill)
item  item_name  qty   price  total
1     hamburgers  2    10      20
2     fries       2    3       6
3     water       1    2       2
```

I want to add a row at the bottom with total bill, but only for total column like so:

```
item  item_name  qty  price  total
1     hamburgers  2   $ 10   $20
2     fries       2   $ 3    $6
3     water       1   $ 2    $2 
                  total bill $28
```

I do this:

```py
bill.loc['total bill'] = bill['total'].sum()
```

but the total is added to each column like so:

```py
item  item_name  qty  price  total
1     hamburgers  2   10     20
2     fries       2   3      6
3     water       1   2      2 
total bill     28  28   28  28
```

But I wish total bill to be only under total.
I googled how to to this but I haven't found anything to add total under just one column. Further I will like to replace all values for `bill['price']` and `bill['total']` with $values, adding `$`sign

Comment: Do you want `df.loc['total bill', 'total'] = df['total'].sum()`?

Comment: I tried this too prior to asking here and for the rest of the columns is showing NaN, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: Would you want the same wihout the NaNs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc['total bill'] = df[['total']].sum().reindex(df.columns, fill_value='')
```

Output:

```
           item   item_name qty price  total
0             1  hamburgers   2    10     20
1             2       fries   2     3      6
2             3       water   1     2      2
total bill                                28
```

If you further want the `$` sign:

```
cols = ['price', 'total']
df[cols] = df[cols].astype(str).radd('$').where(df[cols].ne(''), '')
```

Output:

```
           item   item_name qty price total
0             1  hamburgers   2   $10   $20
1             2       fries   2    $3    $6
2             3       water   1    $2    $2
total bill                              $28
```